# Logback and different levels

Tags: java, logback

There 3 appenders: STDOUT, FILE-AUDIT and FILE-ERROR. How to log all messages to STDOUT and FILE_AUDIT(including errors), but errors messages dublicate in FILE-ERROR. Part of my logback.xml:

```
<logger level="all"
    additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your `FILE-ERROR` appender with a [`ThresholdFilter`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter):

```
<appender name="FILE_ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>[...]</file>

    <!-- [...] -->

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

Then, simply add all your appenders to root logger:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
</root>
```

This way, `STDOUT` and `FILE-AUDIT` contain all the messages, but `FILE-ERROR` only contains error messages.